# SnackBar запретить убирать при помощи пальца

Tags: android, snackbar

Пытаюсь сделать из SnackBar всплывающее меню с кнопками. В View разобрался, но как сделать что бы его нельзя было закрыть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте флаг `Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE` при создании `Snackbar`. Так снэк не исчезнет со временем и не будет двигаться пальцем, если среди его родителей (точнее среди родителей вьюхи, кою указываете в первом аргументе метода `make`) нет `CoordinatorLayout`-а. Если он есть, то у снэка надо отключить дефолтное поведение в оном. Для этого надо повесить слушатель и в нём достучаться `LayoutParams` снэка и установить поведение `null` - теперь снэк не будет реагировать на свайп даже в `CoordinatorLayout`-е.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "text", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();

final View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
snackbar.show();

snackbarView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        snackbarView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackbarView.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(null);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Этот флаг означает, что система не уберёт его через какое то время, но пользователь может убрать его пальцем

Comment: @RodGers, попробуйте вот так тогда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41581295/3212712

Comment: а вот это сработало, спасибо, сделай ответом приму. Хорошо будет если немного опишешь что тут происходит

Comment: @RodGers, обновил ответ)